# Como crear varias copias de una hoja en el mismo PDF con iTextSharp en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf, itextsharp

Quisiera crear varias copias de una hoja ya creada con iTextSharp y pegarlas en el mismo archivo PDF, me explico:

Estoy haciendo un modulo de un programa para crear las etiquetas de un embarque , y por ejemplo si en un TextBox el usuario ingresa que quiere 6 copias , quiero que el sistema me genere un PDF de 6 hojas con 6 copias de la misma hoja, ya tengo la hoja original generada, lo unico que quiero es copiarla las veces que el usuario lo requiera para generar un solo archivo.
Esta es la etiqueta original:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el codigo que uso para crearla :

```
try
        {

            var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 8f, 8f, 20f, 60f);
            string path = $"C:\\PDFs\\etiqueta.pdf";
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
            pdfDoc.Open();

            iTextSharp.text.Image png = null;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Equipo\Documents\Interfaz\Logo\MembreteTop.png", FileMode.Open))
            {
                png = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                png.ScalePercent(3.3f);
            }

            iTextSharp.text.Image png2 = null;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\PDFs\codigo.png", FileMode.Open))
            {
                png2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                png2.ScalePercent(75f);
            }

            var logo = new PdfPCell(png)
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = 1,
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
            };



            var barras = new PdfPCell(png2)
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = 1,
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
            };


            // cell1.AddElement(png);
            var tablabarras = new PdfPTable(new[] { 1f })
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = Left,
                WidthPercentage = 43,
                DefaultCell = { MinimumHeight = 22f }
            };
            tablabarras.AddCell(logo);
            tablabarras.AddCell(barras);
            pdfDoc.Add(tablabarras);

            iTextSharp.text.Font fuente = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
            //TABLA INICIAL
            var tableTitulo = new PdfPTable(new[] { 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f })
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = Left,
                WidthPercentage = 43,
                DefaultCell = { MinimumHeight = 22f }
            };

            var celrem = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(NumeroOrdenTxt.Text, fuente))
            {
                Colspan = 2, // numero de columnas que va a fusionar de la tabla
                HorizontalAlignment = 1,    //0=Izquierda, 1=Centro, 2=Derecha
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                MinimumHeight = 10f,
            };

            var EtiquetaRem = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("REMISION", fuente))
            {
                Colspan = 2,
                HorizontalAlignment = 1,
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
            };

            var EtiquetaFecha = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("FECHA", fuente))
            {
                Colspan = 4,
                HorizontalAlignment = 1,
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
            };

            var celfech = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(fechastr, fuente))
            {
                Colspan = 4,
                HorizontalAlignment = 1,    //0=Izquierda, 1=Centro, 2=Derecha
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                MinimumHeight = 10f,
            };

            var celruta = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(RutaTxt.Text, fuente))
            {
                Colspan = 2,
                HorizontalAlignment = 1,    //0=Izquierda, 1=Centro, 2=Derecha
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                MinimumHeight = 30f
            };

            var EtiquetaRuta = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("RUTA", fuente))
            {
                Colspan = 2,
                HorizontalAlignment = 1,
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                MinimumHeight = 30f
            };

            var EtiquetaNumCliente = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CLIENTE", fuente))
            {
                Colspan = 4,
                HorizontalAlignment = 1,
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
            };

            var celNumCliente = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(IdClienteTxt.Text + "\n \n" + NombreClienteTxt.Text + " \n \n " + DomicilioTxt.Text, fuente))
            {
                Colspan = 4,
                HorizontalAlignment = 1,    //0=Izquierda, 1=Centro, 2=Derecha
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                MinimumHeight = 10f,
            };

            EtiquetaRem.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 209, 187);
            EtiquetaFecha.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 209, 187);
            EtiquetaRuta.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 209, 187);
            EtiquetaNumCliente.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 209, 187);
            tableTitulo.AddCell(EtiquetaRem);
            tableTitulo.AddCell(celrem);
            tableTitulo.AddCell(EtiquetaRuta);
            tableTitulo.AddCell(celruta);

            tableTitulo.AddCell(EtiquetaFecha);
            tableTitulo.AddCell(celfech);
            tableTitulo.AddCell(EtiquetaNumCliente);
            tableTitulo.AddCell(celNumCliente);

            var NumeroPaquetes = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("\n BULTOS: 1 DE 5 \n \n", fuente))
            {
                Colspan = 4,
                HorizontalAlignment = 1,
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
            };

            var celCajas = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(CajasTxt.Text, fuente))
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = 1,    //0=Izquierda, 1=Centro, 2=Derecha
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                MinimumHeight = 10f,
            };

            var EtiquetaCajas = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CAJAS", fuente))
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = 1,
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
            };

            var EtiquetaBolsas = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("BOLSAS", fuente))
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = 1,
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
            };

            var celBolsas = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(BolsasTxt.Text, fuente))
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = 1,    //0=Izquierda, 1=Centro, 2=Derecha
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                MinimumHeight = 10f,
            };
            EtiquetaCajas.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 209, 187);
            EtiquetaBolsas.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 209, 187);
            tableTitulo.AddCell(NumeroPaquetes);
            tableTitulo.AddCell(EtiquetaCajas);
            tableTitulo.AddCell(celCajas);
            tableTitulo.AddCell(EtiquetaBolsas);
            tableTitulo.AddCell(celBolsas);

            pdfDoc.Add(tableTitulo);

            pdfDoc.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Exportación Exitosa", "Exportar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            Process.Start("C:/PDFs/etiqueta.pdf");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Imagino que bastaria con pegarla en un ciclo con una instruccion que cree una nueva hoja hasta que se alcancen las solicitadas pero no se la instruccion necesaria, si alguien supiera como podria hacerlo se lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: Huy tengo lo que necesitas pero en Java(Itext) no tengo instalado el visual studio para ponerme a probar, pero proba abajo del pdfDoc.Open(); hacer el ciclo for y cerrarlo arriba del pdfDoc.Close(); agrega doc.NewPage(); apenas entra a recorrer el for.
creo que doc.newPage es lo que necesitas, en java yo lo hago con PdfContentByte content;
content = pdfStamper.getOverContent(i); // la i del for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si esque entendí tu pregunta...

Yo agregaría un método para agrupar la etiqueta que generas.

ejemplo:

```
private void EtiquetasEmbarque(Document pdfDoc)
{
    try
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Image png = null;
         using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Equipo\Documents\Interfaz\Logo\MembreteTop.png", FileMode.Open))
        {
            png = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            png.ScalePercent(3.3f);
        }

        // TODO lo demas código hasta....
        // ....

        tableTitulo.AddCell(NumeroPaquetes);
        tableTitulo.AddCell(EtiquetaCajas);
        tableTitulo.AddCell(celCajas);
        tableTitulo.AddCell(EtiquetaBolsas);
        tableTitulo.AddCell(celBolsas);
        pdfDoc.Add(tableTitulo);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Y en otro método distinto tendrias que generar el documento, y es ahí donde generas el ciclo con el numero de copias que se desea (en este caso es estático con 6).
Ejemplo:

```
private void generarDocumento()
{
    var pdfDocumento = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 8.0F, 8.0F, 20.0F, 60.0F);
    string path = $"C:\\PDFs\\etiqueta.pdf";
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocumento, new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite));
    pdfDocumento.Open();
    var intNumeroCopias = 6;
    for (int i = 1; i <= intNumeroCopias; i++)
    {
        EtiquetasEmbarque(pdfDocumento);
        pdfDocumento.NewPage();     // Con esta instruccion se indica que se genere una nueva hoja...
    }

    pdfDocumento.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Exportación Exitosa", "Exportar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    Process.Start("C:/PDFs/etiqueta.pdf");
}
```

Y con esto se genera (en este ejemplo) 6 hojas con el mismo contenido...

Comment: Si entendiste bien, justo eso era lo que necesitaba , gracias